# a href is not working, url is getting updated in address bar, but page does not get updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

I have few links on header, When i click on Compare, compare.jsp loads, but from there where-ever i click on header, nothing is loading. i could see the address bar is updated with new url, but the page is not getting refreshed with the new jsp. Can anyone help what i miss here?

```
<div id="header">
<a class="menus" id="idHome" href="uoi.jsp">Home</a>
<a class="menus" id="idSearch" href="search.jsp">Search</a>
<a class="menus" id="idQuick" href="digest.jsp">Quick Reference</a>
<a class="menus" id="idAbout" href="dashboard.jsp">AboutMe</a>
<a class="menus" id="idAlert" href="alert.jsp?type=alert#alerts/criteria">Alerts</a>
<a class="menus" id="idCompare" href="compare.jsp" style="padding-right: 0px;">Compare
    <sup style="color:#ffc00f;">BETA</sup>
</a>
<a class="menus" id="idCalc" href="uoiservice.jsp" style="padding-right: 0px;">idCalc
    <sup style="color:#ffc00f;">BETA</sup>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What is header here ?

Comment: `href="/compare.jsp"`

Comment: Take a look at your [console](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/642/debugging/10108/using-the-console#t=20160723135949497454), if you are seeing some errors.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to include the base url on the href attribute.